# useState react hook does not set the array state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set the videos state to the items array of the response from the api but when I console.log the videos it returns an empty array....
Here is the code to fetch the api in which I set the videos state

```
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
const handleFormSubmit = async (searchterm) => {
    await fetch(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?${params.toString()}&q=${searchterm}`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setVideos(data.items);
        console.log(videos);
      });
  };
```

How do I set the items array to the videos state?

Comment: `setVideos` is not a synchronous operation, the videos array will change the next time the functional component is rendered.

Comment: You can't log updated state right after calling `setVideos`. Your state is getting updated, your component will have to re-render to see the updated state. Also make sure you have a `catch` block to catch and handle any errors that might occur during the request.

Comment: Not related to your problem but either use `async-await` syntax or promise chaining, don't mix both of them.

Answer (score 7):

Ciao, unfortunately with hooks you cannot log `videos` after `setVideos` call because `setVideos` is async.

To get the last value of `videos` you have to use `useEffect` hook in this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(videos);
}, [videos]);
```

Comment: Yeah Exactly what I want to say

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

> React Hooks work async `setState` -> `render` -> `state binding`

### Answer

react hooks is working like that

1. setState
2. schedule render component ( I mean state changed component)
3. and render with changed state

So, You couldn't access video at that `console.log(video)`

### Reference

1. [Overreact](https://overreacted.io/ko/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)
2. [My medium with korean (You can translate with google)](https://medium.com/react-native-seoul/react-%EB%A6%AC%EC%95%A1%ED%8A%B8%EB%A5%BC-%EC%B2%98%EC%9D%8C%EB%B6%80%ED%84%B0-%EB%B0%B0%EC%9B%8C%EB%B3%B4%EC%9E%90-04-functional-component%EC%99%80-usestate-e70b60962f95)
3. [How does React Hooks re-renders a function Component?](https://medium.com/swlh/how-does-react-hooks-re-renders-a-function-component-cc9b531ae7f0)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `async/await`, so it should be

```js
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([])
const handleFormSubmit = async (searchterm) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?${params.toString()}&q=${searchterm}`
  )
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)
  setVideos(data.items)
  console.log(videos)
}
```

Comment: Nono, setVideos is async!!! Your solution it doesn't work at all!!!

Comment: Yes, I tries doing that but it still returns an empty array! :(

Comment: OP is trying to log the updated state right after calling `setVideos` which won't work. Using promise chaining inside an `async` function isn't the problem here.

Comment: @premkulkarni did you add the API key for the request?

Comment: The way I see it it doesn't matter cuz of it working same process